# How to add a Image with some transperacy in tkinter, pillow

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-imaging-library, png

```
class window(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.pack()
        img = Image.open(os.path.join(sys.path[0], 'example.png')).convert("RGBA")
        img = img.resize((150, 200), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        imgg = ImageTk.PhotoImage(img)
        pic = tk.Label(image=imgg)
        pic.pack()
```

It only shows me a white Box
here is the image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8h5o.jpg
what can i do? :(

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does Tkinter image not show up if created in a function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16424091/why-does-tkinter-image-not-show-up-if-created-in-a-function)

Comment: If you wish to show a PNG image with alpha then you should use `canvas.create_image()`.